# 2 Wireless Routers daisy chained for two WAPs from one modem

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have a Linksys Wireless N router with 4 ports.  The cable modem comes in through the basement and as a result the wireless signal doesn't reach upstairs very well.  All 4 ports on the router are taken.

Can I use a spare Linksys Wireless G router daisy chained on the Wireless N router?  I can sacrifice one port on the Wireless N to plug in the Wireless G like, leaving me with the following setup:

- Cable Modem --> Wireless N WAN
- Wireless N Outgoing Port --> Wireless G Wan
- Wireless G ---> Upstairs Wi-Fi and 4 extra ports.

As set up, when I connect to the WiFi through the Wireless G router, I have limited network connectivity and can't connect to the greater Internet through it. How can I use the Wireless G router, connected to the cable modem through the N router, in a way that allows for ful network connectivity, maximizes wireless range and LAN ports?

Comment: This should work, what IP ranges are you using on each network?

Comment: Forgive me for the noobishness, but 192.168.1.1-255 (i guess?)

Comment: I found this and it works: http://www.ezlan.net/router_AP.html

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like the following:

1. config AP-N with SSID-N and IP range 0-127
2. config AP-G with SSID-G and IP range 128-255
3. flip AP-G 'backwards' and connect them by what is normally the client side of the AP
4. point all devices at AP-N for the gateway

This gives to two SSIDs with non-overlapping IP ranges that are still technically on the same subnet (assuming that you use a /24 netmask). It also avoids the double NAT.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn off the DHCP server on the second router.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly do this, but "nested" NAT could make port forwarding ridiculously stupid. It will also increase your overall error/retransmit rate and introduce latency.

Make room on the cable modem. Consider getting a workgroup switch.

Comment: And what part of this "Answer" actually answers his question?